# Is there a file on R projects where I can find out which packages and which versions are installed?

Tags: r

I'm a newbie on R and I will run a R project on a remote server and I just want to make sure that it will also work there like it does on my machine and also ensure that the same versions of all packages will be installed there.

1. How does R knows which package and which versions should be installed?
2. Are all the packages versions listed on a file? Like the package.json on an npm, angular project, where all the packages and dependencies with versions are listed.
3. Is there a way to find out which packages versions are installed on my project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) It doesn't, it just gives you an error when a dependency fails. (2) No, not in base R. (3) You can see the packages *loaded* with `search()`, but that's not clearly associated with the current project. You might check out `renv` if you have dependency requirements within a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved that using [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html)

1. `renv::init()`
2. `renv::settings$snapshot.type("all") # if you want to list all`
3. `renv::snapshot()`

Then the `renv.lock` file will be updated with the state of the project libraries where you can find all libraries listed. Something similar to this:

```
{
  "R": {
    "Version": "4.0.3",
    "Repositories": [
      {
        "Name": "CRAN",
        "URL": "https://cran.rstudio.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Packages": {
    "KernSmooth": {
      "Package": "KernSmooth",
      "Version": "2.23-17",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "bbff70c8c0357b5b88238c83f680fcd3"
    },
    "MASS": {
      "Package": "MASS",
      "Version": "7.3-53",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "d1bc1c8e9c0ace57ec9ffea01021d45f"
    },
    "Matrix": {
      "Package": "Matrix",
      "Version": "1.2-18",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "08588806cba69f04797dab50627428ed"
    },
    "R6": {
      "Package": "R6",
      "Version": "2.5.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "b203113193e70978a696b2809525649d"
    },
    "Rcpp": {
      "Package": "Rcpp",
      "Version": "1.0.5",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "125dc7a0ed375eb68c0ce533b48d291f"
    },
    "assertthat": {
      "Package": "assertthat",
      "Version": "0.2.1",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "50c838a310445e954bc13f26f26a6ecf"
    },
    "boot": {
      "Package": "boot",
      "Version": "1.3-25",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "bd51734a754b6c2baf28b2d1ebc11e91"
    },
    "class": {
      "Package": "class",
      "Version": "7.3-17",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "9267f5dab59a4ef44229858a142bded1"
    },
    "cli": {
      "Package": "cli",
      "Version": "2.2.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "3ef298932294b775fa0a3eeaa3a645b0"
    },
    "cluster": {
      "Package": "cluster",
      "Version": "2.1.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "db63a44aab5aadcb6bf2f129751d129a"
    },
    "codetools": {
      "Package": "codetools",
      "Version": "0.2-16",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "89cf4b8207269ccf82fbeb6473fd662b"
    },
    "crayon": {
      "Package": "crayon",
      "Version": "1.3.4",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "0d57bc8e27b7ba9e45dba825ebc0de6b"
    },
    "digest": {
      "Package": "digest",
      "Version": "0.6.27",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "a0cbe758a531d054b537d16dff4d58a1"
    },
    "dplyr": {
      "Package": "dplyr",
      "Version": "1.0.2",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "d0509913b27ea898189ee664b6030dc2"
    },
    "ellipsis": {
      "Package": "ellipsis",
      "Version": "0.3.1",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "fd2844b3a43ae2d27e70ece2df1b4e2a"
    },
    "fansi": {
      "Package": "fansi",
      "Version": "0.4.1",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "7fce217eaaf8016e72065e85c73027b5"
    },
    "foreign": {
      "Package": "foreign",
      "Version": "0.8-80",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "ae1b1e15cc6ccb2bc61c0ac33e86d35f"
    },
    "generics": {
      "Package": "generics",
      "Version": "0.1.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "4d243a9c10b00589889fe32314ffd902"
    },
    "glue": {
      "Package": "glue",
      "Version": "1.4.2",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "6efd734b14c6471cfe443345f3e35e29"
    },
    "lattice": {
      "Package": "lattice",
      "Version": "0.20-41",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "fbd9285028b0263d76d18c95ae51a53d"
    },
    "lifecycle": {
      "Package": "lifecycle",
      "Version": "0.2.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "361811f31f71f8a617a9a68bf63f1f42"
    },
    "magrittr": {
      "Package": "magrittr",
      "Version": "2.0.1",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "41287f1ac7d28a92f0a286ed507928d3"
    },
    "mgcv": {
      "Package": "mgcv",
      "Version": "1.8-33",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "eb7b6439bc6d812eed2cddba5edc6be3"
    },
    "nlme": {
      "Package": "nlme",
      "Version": "3.1-149",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "7c24ab3a1e3afe50388eb2d893aab255"
    },
    "nnet": {
      "Package": "nnet",
      "Version": "7.3-14",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "0d87e50e11394a7151a28873637d799a"
    },
    "pillar": {
      "Package": "pillar",
      "Version": "1.4.7",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "3b3dd89b2ee115a8b54e93a34cd546b4"
    },
    "pkgconfig": {
      "Package": "pkgconfig",
      "Version": "2.0.3",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "01f28d4278f15c76cddbea05899c5d6f"
    },
    "plyr": {
      "Package": "plyr",
      "Version": "1.8.6",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "ec0e5ab4e5f851f6ef32cd1d1984957f"
    },
    "purrr": {
      "Package": "purrr",
      "Version": "0.3.4",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "97def703420c8ab10d8f0e6c72101e02"
    },
    "remotes": {
      "Package": "remotes",
      "Version": "2.2.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "430a0908aee75b1fcba0e62857cab0ce"
    },
    "renv": {
      "Package": "renv",
      "Version": "0.12.3-8",
      "Source": "GitHub",
      "RemoteType": "github",
      "RemoteHost": "api.github.com",
      "RemoteRepo": "renv",
      "RemoteUsername": "rstudio",
      "RemoteRef": "HEAD",
      "RemoteSha": "080234134766804fb1dbbd777dff77dffff4b2e6",
      "Hash": "cf80821fca4292cf8af159b24d422536"
    },
    "rlang": {
      "Package": "rlang",
      "Version": "0.4.9",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "9d7aba7bed9a79e2403b4777428a2b12"
    },
    "rpart": {
      "Package": "rpart",
      "Version": "4.1-15",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "9787c1fcb680e655d062e7611cadf78e"
    },
    "spatial": {
      "Package": "spatial",
      "Version": "7.3-12",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "58a02ce0150652b96c044bc67a0df2e5"
    },
    "survival": {
      "Package": "survival",
      "Version": "3.2-7",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "39c4ac6d22dad33db0ee37b40810ea12"
    },
    "tibble": {
      "Package": "tibble",
      "Version": "3.0.4",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "71dffd8544691c520dd8e41ed2d7e070"
    },
    "tidyselect": {
      "Package": "tidyselect",
      "Version": "1.1.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "6ea435c354e8448819627cf686f66e0a"
    },
    "utf8": {
      "Package": "utf8",
      "Version": "1.1.4",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "4a5081acfb7b81a572e4384a7aaf2af1"
    },
    "vctrs": {
      "Package": "vctrs",
      "Version": "0.3.5",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "d25c5bea636cf892edbfd64fc3d20c20"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question #2:

Running

```
installed.packages()
```

from package **utils** you'll get in matrix form all installed packages and some other informations.

Here's the documentation of the function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/installed.packages.html